# Замена символов в строке(c++)

Tags: c++, строки, указатели, const

Код который должен заменять символы, но он выдает ошибку

```
const char* mess[] = { "aba" };
const char* test;
int n = strlen(mess);
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (mess[i] == "a") test[i] = "b";
    if (mess[i] == "b") test[i] = "a";
}
```

Ошибка: выражение должно быть допустимым для изменения левосторонним значением (test)

Answer (score 2):

```
const char* mess[] = { "aba" };
```

Ну, обычный нормальный массив... Заметим - массив **указателей**.

```
const char* test;
```

Указатель *куда-то* - неизвестно куда, но на *неизменяемый* (константный) символ.

```
int n = strlen(mess);
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
```

Ну, тут понятно - по всем символам *первого* элемента в массиве `mess`.

```
    if (mess[i] == "a") test[i] = "b";
    if (mess[i] == "b") test[i] = "a";
```

Т.е. пытаемся менять *неизменяемые* символы? Компилятор против. Вот если бы `test` был объявлен как `char * test;`... Правда, все равно бы не работало - присваивать символу указатель на строку все равно нельзя.

И это очень хорошо - потому что если бы он это разрешил, вашим следующим вопросом было бы "почему программа вылетает"? Кстати, вы уже поняли, почему? Причин две: выход за пределы массива `mess` - в нем только один элемент, а длина первого элемента - 3. А вторая - запись по случайному адресу через `test`.

И еще - мне думается, что вы вот тут - `mess[i] == "a"` - *хотели* проверить совсем иное. Сейчас вы проверяете, равен ли *адрес*, хранящийся в `i`-м элементе массива, адресу строки `"a"`. Конечно, нет...

Мне кажется, что вы хотели чего-то в этом роде:

```
const char mess[] = "aba";
char* test = new char[strlen(mess)+1];
strcpy(test,mess);

int n = strlen(mess);

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
{
    if (mess[i] == 'a') test[i] = 'b';
    if (mess[i] == 'b') test[i] = 'a';
}
```